# Can anyone help me get this map app working?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

The problem is that my map isn't showing. It's just the grid that shows when you (for example:) haven't got the INTERNET permission.

Here's my java class:

```
public class MapClass extends MapActivity {

 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onCreate(icicle);
  setContentView(R.layout.maplayout);

  MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
  mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }
}
```

Here's my XML Layout file (minus the Map Key):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/mainlayout" android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
  android:id="@+id/mapView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:enabled="true" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:clickable="true" android:apiKey="MY-API-KEY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's my Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.android.mapexample" android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="internalOnly">

 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:debuggable="true">

  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
  <activity android:name=".MapClass" android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

   <intent-filter>

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

   </intent-filter>>

  </activity>
 </application>

 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: My guess would be that the API Key is wrong. Are you sure you generated it properly?

Comment: I thought that too. I have generated it about 10 times now, on multiple computers. I have also copied the MapView XML code straight from Google where they generated the key just in case I was messing something up there. Still nothing.

Comment: Are you testing it on the emulator? If so have you already updated to the new ADT?

Comment: I am testing it on the emulator and a HTC Desire. I have every version of the emulator running Google APIs, (including 2.3 which looks awesome). When I click maps on the phone and emulator, everything works fine, then in my app there's nothing. Also, yeah I have the new ADT. It's amazing, although I haven't been able to use it to it's full potential yet because of this problem :(

Comment: @TehGoose: so it does not work on the device neither?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work on the device either. Google Maps does, Navigation does, but my app does not. I'm pretty sure I followed Google's dev starter guide step-by-step.

Comment: And you are not signing it with the release key-store?

Comment: Nope. I am just running it on my device through USB. Thanks for all the suggestions btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your app is signed with the signing key you associated with your Map API key. I suspect you are debugging, so the app is signed with the debug keystore...you have to generate a different Map API key for that.

I keep 2 layouts, one for each Map API key. I dynamically choose my layout based on whether I am running in a debug or release build.

Comment: I'm not signing my app because I am not creating the APK. I am just running it in the emulator and debugging on my phone. Is there another way to sign an app? The only way I know how is to create an APK with the key, copy it to my phone, and then install it.

Comment: Hmmm. Making the APK and then copying it to my phone works. That is strange because I had it working in the emulator last year and I have never heard of a debug key. Thanks

Comment: When you run/debug an app on a device/emulator from Eclipse, the APK is generated and signed with the debug signing key. If you want to deploy an app in the Android Market, you need to create your own signing key and sign the APK with it. Read up on this at

Comment: Your Google Maps API key is specific to a signing key, so you need one for both debug key and your personal key.